# Why my map not working with MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to create the planet Earth with three.js. I used a texture on a `MeshBasicMaterial` and it worked perfectly, but when I change the material to a `MeshPhongMaterial` it just doesn't render the map anymore.

I want to change the material because I want to add a bump Map too.

Here's my code:

```
let renderer;

const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 50, 50);

const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../img/globe.jpg"),
  //   bumpMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../img/earthbump.jpg"),
  //   bumpScale: 0.3,
});
```

const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
scene.add(sphere);

And there's not a single problem in the console so I don't know what to do.
I'm also using svelte and vite, maybe it can come from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used a texture on a MeshBasicMaterial and it worked perfectly, but when I change the material to a MeshPhongMaterial it just doesn't render the map anymore.

If it does work with `MeshBasicMaterial` but not with `MeshPhongMaterial`, you most likely have no lights in your scene. Try it with this basic setup:

```js
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
directionalLight.position.set( 100, 100, 0 );
scene.add( directionalLight );
```